# how to remove <app-header> tag for login and add it back in other routes in angular 9

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript, angular9

i am trying to build an app in Angular 9 (MEAN Stack) in which i need to remove the  tag and its content in login route and once logged in the tag should come back to show its content. Please look at my codes below and help me in guiding to solve this.

**Login.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef, } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {BackendService} from '../services/backend.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit,  OnDestroy{
  title = 'Login';
  error = false;
errorMessage = '';

private querySubscription: { unsubscribe: () => void; };
  dataLoading = false;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  constructor(private _backendService: BackendService, private _route: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      this._route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } else {
      const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
      body.classList.add('login');
      wrapper.classList.add('wrapper-login');
      $('#headertopbar').hide();
      $('#sidebar').hide();
      $('.custom-template').remove();
    }
  }

  login(formData: any){
    this.dataLoading = true;
    this.querySubscription = this._backendService.login(formData).subscribe((res: { errorCode: number; errorMessage: string; }) => {
      if (res.errorCode > 0) {
          this.error = false;
          this.errorMessage = '';
          this.dataLoading = false;
          const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
          const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
          // tslint:disable-next-line: align
           this._route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
          window.localStorage.setItem('token', res['data'].token);
          console.log('Success');
          body.classList.remove('login');
          wrapper.classList.remove('wrapper-login');
          $('#headertopbar').show();
          $('#sidebar').show();
          $('.custom-template').add();
      } else {
          this.error = true;
          this.errorMessage = res.errorMessage;
          this.dataLoading = false;
      }
  },
      (error: { message: string; }) => {
          this.error = true;
          this.errorMessage = error.message;
          this.dataLoading = false;
      },
      () => {
          this.dataLoading = false;
      });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  if (this.querySubscription) {
    this.querySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
}

}
```

in the above code i just hidden the div by calling its class property.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.routing.component.html**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ItemMasterComponent } from './item-master/item-master.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent, },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'item-master', component: ItemMasterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Login Page**

[image]

**Dashboard with header**

[image]

Comment: This really worked out. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use here `data` of a route, and to add there flag that you don't want to display the header `data: {header: false}`.
Then in the component based on the active route to fetch the data of it and to add `*ngIf="header !== false"` in the template whether to display `app-header`.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please give me a code placement to show where i shld do header false

Comment: Hi, the guy commented your question with the link has nice samples. there in answers you can find the example with the `data` property. but the thing with two `path: ""` works well too in case if layouts differs a lot.